# Distinguishing and Executing `set` & `env`?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, environment-variables, configure

- ***What*** is the difference between the `set` and `env` commands?
- ***When*** would/should one be used as opposed to the other?
- ***How*** are they generally invoked? (Typical use; case scenario).

Comment: env: environment variables set by the system at boot time. set - are set by the user runs a BASH script.  setx (windows command) - actually creates a new system variable like: JAVA_HOME or CATALINA_home.

Answer (score 3):

## set

`set` is a **shell builtin** command.

*(Since this question is tagged as Unix shells, I’m omitting the MS Windows command.)*

### POSIX specification

The `set` builtin is [defined in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) with a number of features.

#### 1. Positional parameters

The primary purpose of the `set` builtin is to

> set or unset options and positional parameters.

[Positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html) are passed to the shell (usually a script – but can be interactive) as arguments by the calling program – usually (but not necessarily) another shell. The first parameter is available as `$1`, the second as `$2`, etc.

The `set` command can manipulate these parameters. Each *argument* supplied to it is set to be a positional parameter, e.g.

```
$ set one two
$ echo "$1"
one
$ echo "$2"
two
```

`set --` unsets all positional parameters:

```
$ set --
$ echo $1   # no output
```

#### 2. List shell variables

However, the POSIX specification also describes other uses for `set`:

Running `set` by itself prints the names and values of all shell variables.  This includes

- all *shell variables* set within the current shell and
- all *environment variables* inherited from its parent process.

Example:

```
$ set

HOME='/home/ant'
IFS='
'
LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
LANGUAGE='en_US:en'
PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
PS1='# '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PWD='/home/ant'
```

In the above listing, `HOME`, `LANG` and `PATH` are *environment variables* while `IFS` and `PS1` to `PS4` are all *shell variables* that have been set in the current shell.

Note: In the Bash shell, the `set` builtin also prints the definitions of shell functions. For more info, see the Bash manual for set.

#### 3. Control behaviour of the shell

`set` is also used to control the attributes of the shell, usually (but not necessarily) an interactive shell. This is done by running it with certain pre-defined *options* (to distinguish them from arguments that are used to set positional parameters as described above).

> When options are specified, they shall set or unset attributes of the shell

These options are detailed in the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). One example is

```
set -f
```

The `-f` option disables pathname expansion (globbing) from being carried out by the current shell. This behaviour can also be configured with the equivalent command:

```
set -o noglob
```

Shells such as Bash expand on this list to include options such as `-B` (or `-o braceexpand`); this turns on brace expansion (a Bash-only features) in the current shell.

---

## env

Unlike `set`, the `env` command is a regular external command, i.e., it’s not part of the shell. By convention (for portability), on every Unix environment the `env` program is an executable file installed into the `/usr/bin` directory.

### POSIX specification

The `env` tool is also [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html).

#### 1. Modify the environment of a command

The primary purpose of the `env` command is to run a command with a different/modified environment.

```
env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
```

The following example runs the `git status` command with two environment variables set:

```
env GIT_DIR=~/notes/.git/ GIT_WORK_TREE=~/notes/ git status
```

The `-i` option with `env` can be used to run a command with an empty environment, i.e., no environment variables are inherited from the parent process.

Note that if only modifying one or two environment variables and using the Bash shell , there’s no
need for `env` as Bash itself can already temporarily modify the environment for one command.
In Bash, the above example could have been simply run as:

```
GIT_DIR=~/notes/.git/ GIT_WORK_TREE=~/notes/ git status
```

#### 2. Print environment variables

If no command is provided, the current environment is printed.

```
$ env

MAIL=/var/mail/root
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
USER=ant
HOME=/home/ant
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Note that this only prints environment variables – not shell variables such as `PS1` or `IFS`.

#### 3. Search the PATH to run an installed program

Another use of `env` is to search the PATH for a command.

It can also be used to run an external command that is shadowed by a shell-specific command.  Since it knows nothing about shell builtins, keywords, functions or aliases (anything defined by the shell and for the shell), it search for executable files in the directories specified by the `PATH` environment variable.

From [Use system command instead of Bash builtin without specifying the full path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242601/22812)

> `env` runs the executable file named by its first argument in a (possibly)
>   modified environment; as such, it does not know about or work with shell
>   built-in commands.

E.g., this command will run the shell builtin version of `echo`:

```
$ echo --version
--version
```

On the other hand, running `echo` through `env` executes the program installed at `/usr/bin/echo`:

```
$ env echo --version
echo (GNU coreutils) 8.15
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

#### 4. Script shebang

The above behaviour is often exploited for use in the shebang (first line) of an executable script to ensure that the correct program is used by the kernel to interpret the script – without needing to specify in which directory the interpreter program has been installed in.

E.g., Python is installed in different locations on different systems (there’s no standard location). The following shebang will cause the script to be run by the `python3` program – as long as it’s installed into one of the directories specified in the `PATH` environment variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This usage can be tested in an interactive shell by typing the following on the command line:

```
$ /usr/bin/env python3 --version
Python 3.2.5
```

From [this excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12751/22812) to **“How does /usr/bin/env know which program to use?”**

> The kernel doesn't want to know about environment variables such as `PATH`.
>   So the name on the shebang line must be an absolute path to an executable.
>
> The main purpose of the `env` command is to run a command with a different
>   environment, but *since it looks up the command name in `$PATH`, it can be
>   used to provide the path of the command to the kernel*.
>
> Although this is not officially guaranteed, historic Unix systems provided
>   `env` in `/usr/bin`, and modern systems have kept that location precisely
>   because of the widespread use of `#!/usr/bin/env`.

Basically, using `env` is more portable as it means the script doesn’t need to know where the preferred binary for the launching command is installed.  See also [Why is it better to use “#!/usr/bin/env NAME” instead of “#!/path/to/NAME” as my shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77586/22812)